# Converting a string of HH:MM:SS to numeric in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is pretty straight forward: convert the string representation into a number representing minutes. The only problem is that my code only works when I type the HH:MM:SS within a set of "". If the quotes are not included, the code runs but I get a #value error inside the cell in Excel. I figured this has to do with the length. With/without the quotes included, the code goes to the first index of the converted character array (or I should say the 0th). Here is my code:

```
Public Function TimeToDbl(val As String)

'Convert string into character array
Dim buff() As String
ReDim buff(Len(val) - 1)
For i = 1 To Len(val)
    buff(i - 1) = Mid$(val, i, 1)
Next

'Separate hours,minutes,seconds
Dim h, m, s As Double

h = 0
m = 0
s = 0

For i = 1 To 2
    h = (h * 10 ^ (i - 1)) + CInt(buff(i))
Next i

For i = 4 To 5
    m = (m * 10 ^ (i - 4)) + CInt(buff(i))
Next i

For i = 7 To 8
    s = (s * 10 ^ (i - 7)) + CInt(buff(i))
Next i

'Combine values centering minutes
s = s * 0.017
h = h * 60
m = h + m + s

TimeToInt = m
End Function
```

Comment: If you're passing in the value as a string then it needs to be in quotes.  It would help to show an example of exactly how you're calling this from the worksheet.

Comment: Why not make val a double(Which is how Excel stores a date/Time) then simply `TimeToInt = (val - int(val))*24*60`

Comment: Or use this on the worksheet: `=MOD(A1,1)*24*60` to do it with out vba.

Comment: FYI `Dim h, m, s As Double` declares `s` as a `Double`, and leaves `h` and `m` as implicit `Variant`. Avoid declaring multiple variables in a single instruction like this; declare variables just before you assign them, and you'll never have to hunt down unused variables and constantly scroll up and down your code to lookup variable declarations. Your module should have `Option Explicit` at the top, and all variables should be declared.

Comment: The name of the function doesn't make sense.  TimeToInt, but it returns a double?  How about TimeToMinutes?  Strings must be in quotes.  Is the input always HH:MM:SS?  (like 11:34:48 or 02:09:04)  or is it H:M:S?  (like 11:34:48 or 2:9:4)  If this is a time (from a cell on a worksheet), you should be accepting a double.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for the clarification. What would be the datatype of the field if there are no quotation marks? The reason why I ask is because this is output from another program so quotation marks aren't in the best interest. I tried this line to determine the received datatype, but it just says "Range".
`Public Function TimeToInt(val as Object)
MsgBox (TypeName(val))
End Function`

Comment: Try it with Val As Variant

Comment: @TimWilliams it is solved! I passed it in as a variant, then wrote this line:
`MsgBox(TypeName(val.Value))`
to see that it was in fact passed as a string without quotes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When passing a string with quotes, the quotes are included in the string. When the string is copied to an array, arr[0] becomes ". When passed without quotes, the text is still of type "string".

make a small change in the algorithm for h,m, and s shown below:

```
For i = 0 To 1 
h = (h * (10 ^ i) + CInt(buff(i))) 
Next i
```